# Is the grammar for the language $L = \{ a^nb^mc^n \mid n,m \geqslant 0 \}$ correct?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I was doing this grammar.

The language $L = \{ a^nb^mc^n \mid n,m \geqslant 0 \}$

I wanted to know if it is correct or not.

This is my solution

$S \to aSc\mid B \mid e$

$B \to bB \mid e$

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat you question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you want your questions to be well received in this site, please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar is correct. You could save one rule if you wish:

$S \to aSc + B$

$B \to bB + e$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I didn't know it could be done because my professor didn't give us that notation